# Не могу открыть терминал в ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, консоль

С линуксом я сталкиваюсь первый раз, знаний 0...
Скачал VirtualBox от Oracle, поставил на него Ubuntu 22.04 с офф сайта. Всё хорошо, кроме того, что не открывается терминал (который ctrl+alt+T). В активности видно, что процесс начинает грузиться, но завершается без результата, при этом в журнале новых строк не появляется.
Это уже 3 диск, который я создаю. В первом терминал открывался нормально с самого начала, но в том диске я выбрал слишком маленький объём, он переполнился во время работы и начала вылезать ошибка, которая даже после расширения не хотела уходить и решения я не смог найти. Второй - терминал не открывался ни в какую, поэтому я попробовал ещё раз пересоздать диск, но терминал всё равно не открывается.

Вроде как нашел решение своей проблемы, но получился замкнутый круг. Мне нужно внести изменения в определенный конфиг, но чтобы это сделать, надо скачать apt gksu, чтобы получить права для редактирования, а для этого мне нужен терминал, потому что через tty3 прав на скачивание нет, а терминал не работает, а консоль на alt+F2 не может использовать gksu, потому что он не скачан...

upd. В общем, решением оказалось то, что 1 раз я устанавливал дистрибутив в ручную с минимальным набором файлов, попробовал сегодня также - всё работает... 2 и 3 разы я устанавливал автоматом при создании виртуального диска, просто прикладывая образ дистрибутива и видимо virtualbox что-то ломает при установке :(

Comment: нет такой комбинации в убунту 2204

Comment: *`"Всё хорошо, кроме того..."`* -- значит ли это что иксы (рабочий стол, менюшки и т.п.) открываются и какой-там файл-менеджер(?) (у меня в virtualbox xubuntu  и в ней thunar) тоже открывается? Если так, то по правой кнопке мыша обычно можно запустить терминал из файл-менеджера.

Comment: @eri что значит нет, если я вчера ей вызывал консоль весь день. Дистрибутив 22.04 с официального сайта качал

Comment: @avp не запускается ни через что терминал, ни через горячие клавиши, ни через запуск конкретного файла через правую кнопку мыши, более того, сам терминал есть в общем перечне приложений и даже кликая на него там - результата ноль

Comment: «через tty3 прав на скачивание нет» — почему? Кто у вас отобрал sudo в tty3?

Comment: @andreymal не могу вам ответить) после установки дистрибутива на виртуальный диск, их всегда нет, не знаю почему

Comment: sudo в убунте есть всегда даже в виртуалке, так что, похоже, вы делаете что-то очень сильно не так

Comment: @andreymal спорить с вами не буду, может я и делаю что-то не так, но представить что именно - не могу, потому что эти проблемы идут сразу же после установки дистрибутива, я даже сделать своими руками с системой ничего не успеваю, чтобы поломать )

Comment: Ну так всё-таки - что конкретно означает "их всегда нет", как конкретно вы пытаетесь их получить и что конкретно вам отвечает система?

Comment: Спасибо автору за созданный пост. Думал что я что-то не то сделал с виртуальной машиной. В общем, поправил дату, поменял язык и restart

Answer (score 10):

У меня была абсолютно такая проблема. Варианты решения:

1. Через UI: Settings::Region & Language::Login Screen -> явным образом выбираем English (United States) без ISO-8859-1 -> Reboot -> Terminal работает.
2. Через CLI: описано [тут](https://qna.habr.com/q/897955) и [тут](https://askubuntu.com/questions/918558/terminal-wont-open-after-localectl-command-change).

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Это очень странное решение, но оно работает!

Answer (score 0):

Такое бывает или когда нет свободного места или какие-то битые файлы.

В интерфейсе виртуалбокс найдите кнопку "послать сочетание клавиш" -> alt+ctl+f4

Там введите логин и пароль. Наберите команду `df -h` чтоб проверить свободное место. Чтоб проверить запускаемость терминала наберите `DISPLAY=:0 DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus gnome-terminal`

Comment: 230 из 250 ГБ свободно, а дисплей выдаёт: Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: Timeout was reached
На всё, что я нахожу в интернете, необходимы права sudo, но в режиме a+c+f4 у меня их нет и я не могу ничего менять

Comment: на прокси попробуй так

Comment: @ЕвгенийКолесниченко `необходимы права sudo, но в режиме a+c+f4 у меня их нет` — с этого места подробнее, пожалуйста. что именно пытаетесь сделать, что получаете в результате. и пишите это пожалуйста, не в комментарии, а в тексте вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

Терминал это просто программная оболочка интерпретатора **bash**. По **ctrl+alt+f4** как я понял вас в **bash** пускает. Попробуйте использовать `sudo su` и отпишитесь о результатах.

Comment: *facepalm*. про опцию `-i` программы `sudo` вы ничего не знаете?

Comment: В убунте работает и так и так!